# How to change password

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm making an app right now with VisualStudio, and I'm using XAML and C#.
I'm making an app where you can enter a password (existing of numbers only), by clicking on buttons.

If you click on **"button 1",** it will write a **"1"** in a label, and if you click on **"button 2"** afterwards, it will add a **"2",** making it **"12"** in total.

If you enter the correct code, like **"331122",** then you have to press on a button, and a message will pop up saying it is the correct code.

If you fail, then you'll get an error message.

I've also added a **"clear"** button, that wipes out what you've entered. So far so good. Now I want to add a new button, which will bring you to a `passwindow` where you can enter your current password (which is the default password: **"331122"**), and a new password.

If your entered password in the current-password-box matches the default password, your default password will change to the new password you've typed in, if you click on a button below.

If it's incorrect, you'll get an error saying it's incorrect. When you change your password, you should be able to type it in the `MainWindow` app (by clicking the buttons). The old password has to be completely wiped out, and you should be able to keep on changing your password.

I'm stuck on this.

**Here's the code:**

```
string defaultCode = "331122";

public MainWindow()           
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

//string defaultCode = "331122";

private void knop_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Combinatie.Content += "1";
}

private void knop_2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Combinatie.Content += "2";
}

private void knop_3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Combinatie.Content += "3";
}

private void knop_klaar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)label_Combinatie.Content == defaultCode)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unlocked.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You've entered the wrong code. Please try again.");
    }
}

private void knop_reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label_Combinatie.Content = "";
}

private void knop_verander_code_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    passwindow w = new passwindow();
    w.ShowDialog();
}

public passwindow w { get; set; }

private void button_changePw_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string new_code;
    new_code = w.textBox_new_code.Text;
    defaultCode = w.textBox_current_code.Text;

    if (w.textBox_current_code.Text == defaultCode && w.textBox_new_code.Text == new_code)
    {
        defaultCode = "";
        new_code += defaultCode;
        new_code = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Password changed.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You've entered an incorrect code. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Some of the code is in Dutch, so allow me to translate them.

- "Knop" means "Button".
- "Combinatie" --> "Combination".
- "Klaar" -->"Done".
- "Verander" --> "Change".

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two issues in your code that may both in combination cause your problems.

First one:

```
private void knop_verander_code_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    passwindow w = new passwindow();
    w.ShowDialog();
}

public passwindow w { get; set; }
```

In your method `knop_verander_code_Click` you are declaring a local variable `w`, whereas in your class you have declared a property with the same name - the local variable will hide the property.

Second issue:

```
defaultCode = "";
new_code += defaultCode;
new_code = "";
```

Here you are basically clearing your `defaultCode`, adding nothing to your `new_code` and after all you clear `new_code`, too.